# how to use caret symbol in character class to match beginning of a line in Regex

Tags: .net, regex

Good day all . 
I am trying to write regex which matches text that follows dot character or beginning of a line. so i tried this :

```
(?<=[^\.]).
```

obviously, this is not what i want. Problem is that i do not know how to specify caret symbol in character class with meaning of *beginning of a line*, not *negation*. 
P.S. I am using .Net Regee. 
Please give me some suggestions.

Comment: A character class is for characters. You can use the alternation `(?<=^|\.).`

Comment: Thats what i wanted. Thanks.

Comment: Beginning of a line is either right after `\r`/`\n`s or at the string start. You'd better use capturing group mechanism rather than using a lookbehind as lookarounds decrease performance: [`(?:^|[\r\n]+|[.])(.)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3a%5e%7c%5b%5cr%5cn%5d%2b%7c%5b.%5d)(.)&i=Some+.NET+code%0d%0aMore+text).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @stribizhev.

Comment: @Mariano: Just tested at [regexhero](http://regexhero.net) and it turns out they perform similarly (~200K ips on a small 2-line string). Just yours requires the multiline flag.

Comment: @stribizhev Of course. I'll also look into why it's performing similar

Comment: @stribizhev It seems that using groups has a higher impact on performance than the "lookbehind vs. alternation" issue (as always, it all depends on the subject string). **[Benchmark in ideone](http://ideone.com/W6DChe)**

Comment: @Mariano: I am more inclined to think that my regex performance is slowed down due to 3 alternations, while you have just 2. Alternation also invloves backtracking.

Comment: @stribizhev Interesting point. It does have a big impact too. In my test case though, lookbehind is still faster than `(?:^|[\n.])(.)` (again it all depends on the subject). [New benchmark](http://ideone.com/JjYqsl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) only accepts, well, characters. Anchors like `^` are interpreted with a different meaning inside a character class.

Also, the `^` anchor matches the beginning of the line if you pass the flag [`RegexOptions.Multiline`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions(v=vs.110).aspx). If this flag isn't specified, `^` only matches the beginning of the string. **If you have no access to the .NET code, you can still enable this multiline modewith the help of `(?m)` inline modifier that should be used at the start of the whole pattern.**

However, you can use [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to specify different options:

```
(?m)(?<=^|\.)
```

Matches when the cursor is preceded by either:

- `^` Beginning of the line
- `\.` A literal dot